# How do i update each array item into mysqli database in one query

Tags: php, arrays, record

With my code below i have array item with multiple record i which to update each  record into database with one query but only the last item  of each array record was updated here is my code
:

```
<?php
    require("init.php");
    $sql = "SELECT item_name, quantity
    FROM books WHERE book = 1644445";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $da = $row["item_name"];
        $qty = $row["quantity"];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM promo WHERE code = '$da' LIMIT 1");
        $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if($productCount > 0)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                $id = $row["id"];
                $type = $row["name"];
                $code = $row["recharge"];
            }
        }
        $set="123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $coe=substr(str_shuffle($set), 0, 12);
        if(preg_match('/(65265)/i', $type))
            $type   = "20";
        if(preg_match('/(562546)/i', $type))
            $type   = "13";
        if(preg_match('/(MTN)/i', $type))
            $type   = "12";
        if(preg_match('/(56556)/i', $type))
            $type   = "16";
        $disp = str_split($code, $type);
        for($b = 0; $b<$qty; $b++){
            $pin = "$disp[$b]";
            $gam = array(0 => array("post" => $pin));
            foreach($gam as $gg)
            {
                $pp = $gg["post"];
                $go = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE promo SET recharge='$coe$pp' WHERE id=$id");
                if($go)
                {
                    echo "<br/> $pp";
                    echo "<br/> $coe";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

i appliciate your impact

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? If `id` is the primary key of the `promo` table, your update statement is going to update the same row with id=`$id` for each item in the array `$gam`.

Comment: Where do you get the value of $id in your update query ?

Comment: @Sean 
I have multiple arrays with multiple record in query but i got the last record of each arrays updated into the database

Comment: @yfet id value from promo table query

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? If you write it out you'll probably find the problem. How many items are in `$gam`? Do you expect more than one row to be updated in the `promo` table? If you use the same `id`, what makes the entries in the `promo` table unique?

Comment: So the $id might not have a value or the old one value is used because it's initialization is enclosed in a if statement.

Comment: @yfet
Am new here at my knowledge how we i resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    require("init.php");
    $sql = "SELECT item_name, quantity
    FROM books WHERE book = 1644445";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $da = $row["item_name"];
        $qty = $row["quantity"];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM promo WHERE code = '$da' LIMIT 1");
        $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if($productCount > 0)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                $id = $row["id"];
                $type = $row["name"];
                $code = $row["recharge"];
            }

        $set="123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $coe=substr(str_shuffle($set), 0, 12);
        if(preg_match('/(65265)/i', $type))
            $type   = "20";
        if(preg_match('/(562546)/i', $type))
            $type   = "13";
        if(preg_match('/(MTN)/i', $type))
            $type   = "12";
        if(preg_match('/(56556)/i', $type))
            $type   = "16";
        $disp = str_split($code, $type);
        for($b = 0; $b<$qty; $b++){
            $pin = "$disp[$b]";
            $gam = array(0 => array("post" => $pin));
            foreach($gam as $gg)
            {
                $pp = $gg["post"];
                $go = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE promo SET recharge='$coe$pp' WHERE id=$id");
                if($go)
                {
                    echo "<br/> $pp";
                    echo "<br/> $coe";
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

The update is only executed if $productCount > 0.

Comment: This what i have in var_dump
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["post"]=> string(9) "YcZ3xnuhv" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["post"]=> string(9) "HNwuHn101" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["post"]=> string(0) "" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["post"]=> string(0) "" } } array (1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["post"]=> string(0) "" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["post"]=> string(0) "" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["post"]=> string(0) "" } } array (1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["post"]=> string(0) "" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["post"]=> string(0) "" } }